# How to resize ListViewItems horizontally

Tags: listview, datagrid, uwp, resize

I am creating my custom `DataGrid` using `ListView`. But, I am not able to resize my ListViewItems horizontally. I have attached a demo sample for your reference. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Sample Link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxerszZWbaFgy-x7dNZ4wLTrOdF

Answer (score 1):

I always tend to add an unnamed Style inside my apps.
That way the original style is kept but you can tweak your own ListViews the way you like.

So add a `ResourceDictionary` be sure to merge it in your `App.Xaml` and add following unnamed style to the dictionary

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit **ListViewItem** Style. Find **ContentPresenter** and set **HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"** or modify it's **Width**. By default it wraps your content.